# JS: are inner try/catches necessary?

Tags: javascript, async-await, try-catch

**exported js helpers file**

```
export const foo1 = async () =>  {
    const url = "www.foo.com";

    try {
        response = await fetch(url, { method: 'POST'});
    } catch (e) {
        throw new Error(`return another error:${e}`);
    }

    if (response) {
        const responseText = await response.text();

        const blob = responseText.toBlob();
        return blob;
    }
}
```

**main js file**

If I import the `foo1` function in here and put it in a try/catch:

```
try {
   this.fooData = await foo1();
} catch(e) {
   this.error = e
}
```

can I remove the try/catch from `foo1`'s fetch?  Is it now unncessary since I have one in the main function that is invoking `foo1`?

Comment: If there's anything in `foo1` that's outside the existing try block that can throw an error, then you still may want to have the external try/catch.  The inner try block might be used to give more detailed information about the error.  i.e. "exception: tried to fill in the details on the UI, but there was an exception opening a connection to the database because there was an exception reading from the network because there was an exception network interface couldn't find config file X".  Without the inner exceptions, you might have no idea that the real issue was a missing config file.

Comment: Have you tried it? Also `try/catch` should only be used in particular places where the code could fail through no fault of the coder (i.e. network not available, database off line, etc.). They should not be used as "catch alls").